# remove rows based on substraction results

Tags: r

I have a large data set like this:

```
 df <- data.frame(group = c(rep(1, 6), rep(5, 6)), score = c(30, 10, 22, 44, 6, 5, 20, 35, 2, 60, 14,5)) 

      group score
 1      1    30
 2      1    10
 3      1    22
 4      1    44
 5      1     6
 6      1     5
 7      5    20
 8      5    35
 9      5     2
 10     5    60
 11     5    14
 12     5     5
```

...

I want to do a subtraction for each neighboring score within each group, if the difference is greater than 30, remove the smaller score. For example, within group 1, 30-10=20<30, 10-22=-12<30, 22-44=-22<30, 44-6=38>30 (remove 6), 44-5=39>30 (remove 5)... The expected output should look like this:

```
      group score
 1     1    30
 2     1    10
 3     1    22
 4     1    44
 5     5    20
 6     5    35
 7     5    60
```

...

Does anyone have idea about realizing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
repeat {
  df$diff=unlist(by(df$score,df$group,function(x)c(0,-diff(x))))
  if (all(df$diff<30)) break
  df <- df[df$diff<30,]
}
df$diff <- NULL
df
#    group score
# 1      1    30
# 2      1    10
# 3      1    22
# 4      1    44
# 7      5    20
# 8      5    35
# 10     5    60
```

This (seems...) to require an iterative approach, because the "neighboring score" changes after removal of a row. So before you remove 6, the difference `44 - 6 > 30`, but `6 - 5 < 30`. After you remove 6, the difference `44 - 5 > 30`.

So this calculates difference between successive rows by group (using `by(...)` and `diff(...)`), and removes the appropriate rows, then repeats the process until all differences are < 30.

Comment: this seems worked but since my dataset is large, R gave me the following messege: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "diff", value = c(0, 0, -14, 5, -24,  : 
  replacement has 11176 rows, data has 11428

Answer (score 0):

It's not elegant but it should work:

```
out = data.frame(group = numeric(), score=numeric())
#cycle through the groups
for(g in levels(as.factor(df$group))){
    temp = subset(df, df$group==g)
    #now go through the scores
    left = temp$score[1]
    for(s in seq(2, length(temp$score))){
        if(left - temp$score[s] > 30){#Test the condition
            temp$score[s] = NA
        }else{
            left = temp$score[s] #if condition not met then the 
        }   
    }
    #Add only the rows without NAs to the out
    out = rbind(out, temp[which(!is.na(temp$score)),])
}
```

There should be a way to do this using ave but carrying the last value when removing the next if the diff >30 is tricky! I'd appreciate the more elegant solution if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
df
##    group score
## 1      1    30
## 2      1    10
## 3      1    22
## 4      1    44
## 5      1     6
## 6      1     5
## 7      5    20
## 8      5    35
## 9      5     2
## 10     5    60
## 11     5    14
## 12     5     5

tmp <- df[!unlist(tapply(df$score, df$group, FUN = function(x) c(F, -diff(x) > 30), simplify = T)), ]
while (!identical(df, tmp)) {
    df <- tmp
    tmp <- df[!unlist(tapply(df$score, df$group, FUN = function(x) c(F, -diff(x) > 30), simplify = T)), ]
}
tmp
##    group score
## 1      1    30
## 2      1    10
## 3      1    22
## 4      1    44
## 7      5    20
## 8      5    35
## 10     5    60
```